# Combobox with selectable categorys in JQ

Tags: php, jquery, drop-down-menu

I got gorups and cilds. I needed a dopdown where i can select both group and child but i can see if its a main group or not. I did something like this:

[image]

i was wondering if there is any better way to do this, or even if there is a JQ plugin? Any suggestions are wellcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look to this  to [mcDropdown jQuery](http://www.givainc.com/labs/mcdropdown_jquery_plugin.htm) .. easy to use, works with jQuery v1.2.6 (or higher) , easy to customize.

Comment: did you ever used this plugin, do you maybe know if its possible to populate the dropdown with a php array instead of html lists? :)

Comment: u can loop through the php array and create html list as it is there in the document...

Comment: ye thought about that possibility, cool thing i think i take it. Thanks again

Comment: Hi again. I inculded all files, but i get the following error in firebug: TypeError: $.curCSS is not a function

parseInt("0"+$.curCSS(el, "border"+torl+"Width", true), 10) its in the mcdropdown.js

Comment: make sure you laded the script it correct order..
`<script type="text/javascript" src="./lib/jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="./lib/jquery.mcdropdown.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="./lib/jquery.bgiframe.js"></script> 
 
<!---// load the mcDropdown CSS stylesheet //---> 
<link type="text/css" href="./css/jquery.mcdropdown.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />`

Comment: im using 1.8+ jq , and $.curCSS got removed after 1.7.2. i just had to replace it with $.css . Works like a charm. :D